# TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len() when finding mean

Tags: python, mean, azure-machine-learning-service

I am doing a simple operations in Azure ML Studio using Python script.

```
import numpy as np

dt_mean = np.mean(dt.iloc[:,0].values)
```

but it throws error

```
[Critical]     Error: Error 0085: The following error occurred during script evaluation, please view the output log for more information:
---------- Start of error message from Python interpreter ----------
Caught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 211, in batch
    xdrutils.XDRUtils.DataFrameToRFile(outlist[i], outfiles[i], True)
  File "C:\server\XDRReader\xdrutils.py", line 51, in DataFrameToRFile
    attributes = XDRBridge.DataFrameToRObject(dataframe)
  File "C:\server\XDRReader\xdrbridge.py", line 40, in DataFrameToRObject
    if (len(dataframe) == 1 and type(dataframe[0]) is pd.DataFrame):
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
Process returned with non-zero exit code 1
```

This one works perfectly fine in Spyder. But it's not working in Azure ML Python script.

Comment: The error seems to be comming from this line `if (len(dataframe) == 1 and type(dataframe[0]) is pd.DataFrame)` not from the mean calculation

Comment: It looks like the code is checking if `dataframe[0]` is a pandas DataFrame object. What's the type of `dataframe`?